# Why my app stop working as soon as I receive verification SMS using FirebaseAuth?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am learning to use FirebaseAuth using tutorial online. I could successfully get the verification code through SMS but as soon as I receive the SMS the app stopped working. Could you please help me.

I am working on Android Studio and I code in Kotlin.

Here is my code,

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in)

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    phoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.etxPhoneNumber)
    code = findViewById(R.id.etxCode)


    btnCode.setOnClickListener { view: View? ->
        progress.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        verify()
    }


}

private fun verificationCallbacks() {
    mCallbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {


            progress.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            signIn(credential)
        }

        override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException) {

        }

        override fun onCodeSent(p0: String, p1: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(p0, p1)
        }

    }
}

private fun verify() {
    verificationCallbacks()
    val phoneNo = etxPhoneNumber.text.toString()
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(

        phoneNo,
        60,
        TimeUnit.SECONDS,
        this,
        mCallbacks


    )
}


private fun signIn(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<AuthResult> ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                toast("Logged in successfully")
                startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
            }

        }

}
```

It seems like the issue is not resolved. Following is the Logcat (Error).

```
2020-01-25 10:37:08.228 7511-7511/? E/Zygote: v2 2020-01-25 10:37:08.231 7511-7511/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0 2020-01-25 10:37:08.489 7511-7511/com.example.testapp E/FontFamily: Error mapping font file /data/data/com.android.settings/app_fonts/Cooljazz/DroidSans.ttf 2020-01-25 10:37:08.489 7511-7511/com.example.testapp E/FontFamily: Error mapping font file /data/data/com.android.settings/app_fonts/Cooljazz/DroidSans-Bold.ttf 2020-01-25 10:37:08.715 7511-7511/com.example.testapp E/ViewRootImpl@4d50979[MainActivity]: ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid. 2020-01-25 10:37:11.915 7511-7511/com.example.testapp E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]] 2020-01-25 10:37:11.987 7511-7511/com.example.testapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testapp, PID: 7511
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.2.0:7)
        at com.example.testapp.SignIn.verify(SignIn.kt:70)
        at com.example.testapp.SignIn.access$verify(SignIn.kt:19)
        at com.example.testapp.SignIn$onCreate$1.onClick(SignIn.kt:41)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: Add your verification code and/or your Stacktrace please.

Comment: Code added, can you check it? I am just leaning.

Comment: Add the stacktrace as well please.

Comment: I just learned Staktrace after seeing it in your comment repeatedly and in order to give it to you I navigated to the Logcat window and run the app. To my surprise, there was no error shown nor my app crashed. I did not make any change to the code since I posted my question here. I do not know what went wrong then and how come it work now. But, one thing I noticed, then and now, is that there is a grey squiggly line under 'override fun' before onCodeSent with a tool-tip  'Redundant overriding method'. Can you tell me why is it happening.

Comment: Yes sir. It means that you are overriding an empty function (which is not necessary) and you are only calling the super function. You can safely delete it. It is not needed.

Comment: The issue is not resolved and the logcat is added in the question.

Comment: Before calling `verifyPhoneNumber` method check that `phoneNo` is not empty.